# Regex to match a specific pattern multiple times within a sentence

Tags: regex, textmate

I have the following problem with a latex textfile that consist of multiple sentences, e.g.

```
Aaa \cref{fig:1}. Bbb \cref{fig:2} bbb \cref{fig:3}. Ccc \cref{fig:4}. Ddd \cref{fig:5} ddd \cref{fig:6} ddd \cref{fig:7}.
```

What I need to find out is how to isolate the `\cref{fig:xxx}` parts in each sentence. The problem is that the regex should only account for sentences in which `\cref{fig:xxx}` occurs more than one times (>1).

A good result would be if the regex could return `fig:2` and `fig:3` from sentence bbb, as well as `fig:5`, `fig:6`, and `fig:7` from sentence ddd.

I have to use regular expressions for the search in Textmate (texteditor).

Comment: Problem is how a sentence is defined - does it end with a dot? What's it supposed to do with other dots (e.g. with e.g.) ? Does it end with a newline?  As for your second part, you could come up with a regex like [`\\cref{(fig:\d+)}`](https://regex101.com/r/qN3iP9/1)

Comment: Yes, I see ... May it help if the beginning of a sentence would be identified by a dot then some whitespace and begins with an uppercase alpanumeric value. Something like `\.\s+[A-Z0-9]`. The end of a sentence may be identified by a dot and some whitespace `\.\s+`. I know this is tricky, I'm totally lacking the skills for that ...

Comment: You could use a recursive approach, see the [updated demo](https://regex101.com/r/qN3iP9/2), it matches only the sentence bbb, ddd and eee (I made this one up). However, the sentence ending must be clear(er).

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you! I've tried it in Textmate and it was not working because it uses a custom regex engine https://manual.macromates.com/en/regular_expressions. It errors: "Invalid regular expression: undefined group option". If you don't mind having a QUICK look if you find the different syntax it would help me a lot. Anyway, please provide me your answer, I'm more than happy to accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to my comment, you could come up with a recursive approach. However, looking at the documentation, recursion seems not to be supported in `TextMate`. In this case, you could easily repeat the pattern one more time (fulfilling your requirement of sentences with more than **one** occurence):

```
(?:\\cref\{(fig:\d+)\})(?:[^.]+?(?:\\cref\{(fig:\d+)\}))+
```

Broken down, this looks for `\\cref{}` and captures the inner `fig:`+ digit, then looks for a character that is not a dot (`[^.]`) and repeats the first subpattern. As already mentionned in the comments, you will likely need to play around with the sentence conditions (e.g. what is considered as a sentence - this is the `[^.]` part). See a demo of the approach on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/qN3iP9/3).

Comment: Thank you for all your your help, this should help me going!

Comment: @hetsch: No worries, best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

what you need is a positive lookahead statement. eg:

```
\S*(?=\s*\\cref{)
```

note! I'm not sure how to enter escapes and/or symbols in your text program so just to be clear by double "\" I mean the \ char and \s is space char, \S anti space.
to return also the fig, you will need to introduce different groups. this guide might help you:
http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#compound